# root access failed or busybox was not found

Tags: root-access, xposed-framework, busybox

```
Phone: Xiaomi Redmi 4 prime
Rom (custom): lineage-13.0
Xposed: xposed-v87-sdk23-arm64
Root: SuperSU.Pro.2.82
```

Right now everything works just fine and those apps that need root privileges to work properly, asking for root permission and after granting, they work fine;

There's just one app call [Performance Profile](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.h0rn3t.performanceprofile) (an xposed module) that after running asserts that: **"root access failed or busybox was not found"**

I do have successfully installed BusyBox 6.7.3.0

What is the problem with this app?

**Update 1**: I uninstalled BusyBox 6.7.3.0 and installed [BusyBox 1.26.2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.meefik.busybox&hl=en) and using [BusyBox Checker Pro 2.0](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.superdevnl.busyboxcheckerpro&hl=en) got the following results showing that everything is ok.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked if the app has all the neccessary permissions in settings?

Comment: The app was ok with current BusyBox on the rooted stock room. And the only permission that app needs is "storage" which is granted to it already.

Comment: Maybe the module itself doesn't support CyanogenMod 13+?

Comment: @beeshyams
I think the problem is what you've said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

flash rooting using SuperSU-v2.65 solved the problem.

Comment: Glad it got solved

Answer (score 0):

**A wild guess**: You did not correctly install busybox.

[BusyBox](http://busybox.net/) is **not** a simple application, it's a executable binary that should supposedly be located in `/system/xbin`. A correct installation of BusyBox includes copying the binary and creating symbolic links.

Judging by the version number you gave, you might probably installed something like "BusyBox installer" from Google Play or so. The (currently) newest BusyBox binary version is 1.26.1, so you may want to check again if **BusyBox** is installed correctly, **not an app from GP**.

Comment: Based on what you've suggested, I've done some changes that is reflected in the post.